# Creating a network in Docker Swarm

Tags: spring, postgresql, docker, networking, swarm

1. I have a web application on java spring that connects to postgres. Сonnection string to the database: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres`
2. There is a compose-file that raises the web application and the database:

```html
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    networks:
      - backend
    image: postgres
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  worker1:
    networks:
      - backend
    image: scripter51/worker
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
      placement:
      constraints: [node.role == worker]

networks:
  backend:

volumes:
  db-data:
```

3. Public services on the machine of the command `docker stack deploy --compose-file comp.yml test`

Problem: If the database and the web application are on the same machine - everything works, if at different - then the application can not find the database by the name of the service.

Comment: Did you try to specify the network driver? And to create the network external? Did you checked the container IPs in the swarm?

Comment: A network driver is an overlay.
The network is not external.
What do you mean by checking the IP address?

Comment: When I try to specify an external network, I get a message that it should be created in advance.

Comment: If you specify a external network you have to create it via 
    docker network create -d overlay backend
You can do also a docker network inspect (be sure that scope is swarm)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem.
I was trying to create a network between the host and the virtual machine using the means of the docker - apparently it does not work.